# sort vectors in map

Tags: c++, vector, maps, containers

HOW to sort vectors inside a map based on the size of the vectors?

example:

```
map<int, vector<int> >
```

sort based on the size of the vector in order to remove some elements later within the less size.

1,2,3,4
        2,5
        6,7,8

after sort and delete ...

1,2,3,4
       6,7,8
       5

I hope this clarify the intended need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A map is an ordered container on which *the order predicate applies to the key*.

For example you can have a `std::map<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int> >`

Here your key is not the vector, hence you cannot do what you are looking for with your map.

Here maybe you want a `std::map<std::vector<int>, int, some_struct>` where `some_struct` is a functor that defines a strict order  relationship on your vectors.

Comment: @PALASTINO: please show in your original post sample data that you want to store and what you are going to do with the data. Otherwise it is difficult to suggest anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it provided the size of the vector doesn't change:

```
map <int, vector<int> > amap;
vector <int> v;
v.push_back( 42 );
amap.insert( make_pair( v.size(), v ));
```

If the size of the vector does change, you would have to remove the old entry and re-insert.

Comment: @PALASTINO: `amap.erase(amap.begin())` will remove the shortest vector. Maybe you need to read some book about the STL.